# How to limit max height of the document in 100% and fill last child with remaining height available?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set height of `.kpi-view` to get the remaining height available on screen, but i'm getting a overflow. How to set this using flexbox? I also tried `flex: 1` but does not work. I just want scroll inside the list, not on window. Header of kpi-list has a fixed height, i just want to assign the available height to `kpi-view`and prevent scroll on body.

```
  <div className="secao-page">
    <h1 className="page-title">SEÇÃO</h1>
    <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
    <ChangeViewButton />
    <article className="kpi-list">
      <header className="kpi-list__header">
        <QlikObject id="kpi-total" classDOM="kpi-total qv-object" />
      </header>

      <main className="kpi-view">
        <div className="fullscreen hidden">
          <QlikObject id="QV03" classDOM="qv-object detail-table" />
        </div>
        <div className="kpi-item">
          <img
            className="kpi-icon icon-ceramica"
            src="./assets/icones-leroy/icon_materiais.png"
          />
          <QlikObject classDOM="kpi" id="QV02" />
        </div>

        <div className="kpi-item">
          <img
            className="kpi-icon icon-ceramica"
            src="./assets/icones-leroy/icon_ceramicas.png"
          />
          <QlikObject classDOM="kpi" id="QV01" />
        </div>

        <div className="kpi-item">
          <img
            className="kpi-icon icon-ceramica"
            src="./assets/icones-leroy/icon_eletrica.png"
          />
          <QlikObject classDOM="kpi" id="kpi-eletricidade" />
        </div>

        <div className="kpi-item">
          <img
            className="kpi-icon icon-ceramica"
            src="./assets/icones-leroy/icon_ferramentas.png"
          />
          <QlikObject classDOM="kpi" id="QV04" />
        </div>

        <div className="kpi-item">
          <img
            className="kpi-icon icon-ceramica"
            src="./assets/icones-leroy/icon_ceramicas.png"
          />
          <QlikObject classDOM="kpi" id="kpi-pisos" />
        </div>
      </main>
    </article>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can u share some of your styles?

Comment: Did you tried `style="height: calc(100vh - 50px)"` ? for 50px header